# HTML tags being removed from database entry

Tags: php, html, sql, database, wordpress

I did a migration of my WP website - transfered all files and database, configured the settings, updated the urls. Everything is working ok, except one specific database entry: wp_options et_divi, which is where the theme stores some custom metadata and other theme settings.

The problem is that, when I update any of the settings stored in this field, it gets stored with all the html tags and other codes removed/changed.

For example, this Analytics code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'xxxxxxxx', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Is being stored like this:

```
s:409:"
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,\'script\',\'//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js\',\'ga\');

  ga(\'create\', \'xxxxxxxx\', \'auto\');
  ga(\'send\', \'pageview\');

";
```

All the HTML tags are being removed and some slashes are being incorporated.

I think this can be a format/coding issue, but I really don't know what to do. When I backuped the database I chosen the PhpMyAdmin quick export option with SQL format, and when I restored it in the new server, I used the import option with utf-8, SQL format, and NONE SQL compatibility mode options.

But note that it only gets messed when I update any entry inside this field (through the theme's settings page - if I manually restore the field, everything gets back to normal).

So, anyone knows what can be happening here?

**Update 1:** I tried to deactivate all plugins and custom functions, but the same keeps happening.

**Update 2:** This is the array which stores the form field to the "body code integration", used for the Google Analytics code above (file is options_divi.php):

```
array( "name" => esc_html__("Add code to the < body > (good for tracking codes such as google analytics)",$themename),
                   "id" => $shortname."_integration_body",
                   "type" => "textarea",
                   "std" => "",
                   "desc" => esc_html__("Any code you place here will appear in body section of all pages of your blog. This is usefull if you need to input a tracking pixel for a state counter such as Google Analytics.",$themename)
            ),
```

**Update 3**: And this is the header (beginning) of the file above (options_divi.php). I don't know if it can help, but some terms like "htmlspecialchars" gotten my attention (don't know if it is valuable, anyway).

```
<?php
global $epanelMainTabs, $themename, $shortname, $options;

$epanelMainTabs = array('general','navigation','layout','ad','seo','integration','support');

$cats_array = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
$pages_array = get_pages('hide_empty=0');
$pages_number = count($pages_array);

$site_pages = array();
$site_cats = array();
$pages_ids = array();
$cats_ids = array();

foreach ($pages_array as $pagg) {
    $site_pages[$pagg->ID] = htmlspecialchars($pagg->post_title);
    $pages_ids[] = $pagg->ID;
}

foreach ($cats_array as $categs) {
    $site_cats[$categs->cat_ID] = $categs->cat_name;
    $cats_ids[] = $categs->cat_ID;
}

$shortname  = esc_html( $shortname );
$pages_ids  = array_map( 'intval', $pages_ids );
$cats_ids   = array_map( 'intval', $cats_ids );

$options = array ( //... the code goes on with the options arrays
```

If you need any more code/info, just let me know :-)

Comment: Can you share which code is saving your form fields? As it depends on the type of field and data sanitation filters being applied to those codes to strip tags mostly.

Comment: Don't know exactly, Moshin. It's the theme's default functions. Don't know if it helps, but I'm using the ElegantTheme's Divi. I updated it, restored it, removed and installed it again... the same problem keeps happening. Doesn't look like a problem in the theme's functions / broken theme or codes, and since it was working properly before the migration, I think it is something related to the... database/table configuration?

Comment: Anyway, if you know how can I get the saving code (well, I know it is in the theme's php code, but I really don't know where since I'm pretty much a newbie to php...) I can post it here, but I assure you its the theme's default one. Also, as an update, I turned all plugins and custom functions off but the problem still happens.

Comment: if it was working fine before, then I think you should contact the theme author and get their input, maybe they have some clue? Seems like something else going on. Unable to think any cause right now. Yeah please keep adding more info and things you have tried to your question until you solve it or someone give you better insights into it!

Comment: Thanks, Mohsin! I updated the question with some code I found, the one which have the array for that field. It helps? There is anywhere else I can find valuable info/code about this problem?